# OpenCV with Gstreamer installation...possible?

Tags: windows, python, gstreamer, opencv

I have some Python code which utilizes OpenCV in a way to use Gstreamer pipelines in lieu of a webcam or video file as input to a 'Videocapture' command...for a simple example:

send = cv2.VideoCapture('videotestsrc ! appsink', cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER).

My problem is I cannot use OpenCV with Gstreamer, as I am informed by the 'print cv2.getBuildInformation()' command it reports 'Gstreamer = NO'...therefore I am desperately trying to figure how to accomplish getting OpenCV to include the Gstreamer functionality.

I have spent the last several hours in a futile attempt to do this...reading web postings, downloading a massive amount (nearly 3GB) of file/program dependencies, establishing Paths, etc...all without success...

Can anybody please advise on how (or IF) this can be accomplished...preferably using plain English with as little technical verbiage as possible getting in the way?  I cannot believe this is not (easily) possible...however it seems that may be the case...BTW I am on Windows.

I thank you in advance for any advice.  Regards.